# How to move mouse along arc given by 3 points and a length?

Tags: python, geometry

I'm currently working on a section of a program that moves the mouse in an arc.

I'm given three points that define the arc: a starting point `p1`, a intermediate point on the arc `p2` , and the end point `p3`. I'm also given `length` of the arc. If `length` is greater than the actual length of the arc subtended by `p1` and `p3`, then `p3` will not be the end point of the arc, but the mouse will continue moving in a circle until it has traveled distance `length`.

I have worked out the center of the circle `(x, y)`, its radius `r`, and `angle` sweeped.

To move the mouse, am hoping to divide `angle` into smaller intervals each with angle `dAngle` and moving the mouse between its current position and the new position after sweeping `dAngle`. What I have in mind is in the pseudocode below:

```
for i in range(intervals):
    x = center.x + r * cos(i * dAngle)
    y = center.y + r * sin(i * dAngle)
    Move mouse to (x, y)
    Sleep 1
```

However, I've encountered some problems while trying to parametrically find the new point on the arc.

1. My mouse does not start at `p1`, but at what I assume is at the point where the line from the mouse to the center and the horizontal line subtends 0 degees, as I haven't factored into the parameters the initial angle. How do I find the initial angle of the mouse?
2. How do I determine whether to rotate clockwise or anticlockwise, i.e. whether `x = center.x + r * cos(i * dAngle)` or `x = center.x - r * cos(i * dAngle)`

If there is a more efficient way of moving in an arc please suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate starting angle as

```
a1 = math.atan2(p1.y-center.y, p1.x-center.x)
```

then use it in

```
x = center.x + r * cos(a1 + i * dAngle)
y = center.y + r * sin(a1 + i * dAngle)
```

About direction - perhaps you can determine direction when arc center is calculated. If no, and arc sweep angle is less than Pi (180 degrees), just find sign of expression

```
sg = math.sign((p1.x-center.x) * (p3.y-center.y) - (p1.y-center.y) * (p3.x-center.x))
```

and use it with `dAngle`

```
x = center.x + r * cos(a1 + i * sg * dAngle)
similar for y
```

P.S. note that minus in `x = center.x - r * cos(i * dAngle)` is wrong way to change direction